# How to only use the most relevant combination of words in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to make a conversation with an AI like system, and I've been coding different conversations of words.

I currently have:

```
hi = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Sup', 'Howdy', 'Hey']
bye = ['Bye', 'Goodbye', 'Power down', 'Power off']
why = ['Why', 'For what']
hlp = ['Help', 'Assistance', 'Assistant', 'Aid']
med = ['Medical', 'Health']
like = ['Like', 'Enjoy', ]


name = str(input("Hello, I am Xavier. What is your name?\n"))
name = name.capitalize()
if name == 'D':
  name = 'Creator'
print("\nHello there, " + name + ", I am here to be your virtual best friend, what ever I can do, I will do for you.\n")
while True:
  import random
  user_input = (input("\nInput\n>>> ")).capitalize()
  user_input = user_input.split(" ")
  for word in user_input:
    if word in hi and word not in bye:
      greeting = random.sample(['Hello there.', 'Howdy partner', 'It is nice to talk to you.', 'Hi friend.', 'Sup mah human!'], 1)
      print (greeting)
    elif word in bye and word not in hi:
      farewell = random.sample(['Goodbye friend.', 'Goodbye', 'Farewell', 'See you later', 'Bye bud', 'Thanks for talking with me.'], 1)
      print(farewell)
      exit()
    elif word in hi and word in bye:
      print("You are confusing me.")
    else:
      els = random.sample(["That is not valid.", "Please try again.", "I apologize, but I do not understand.", "Try typing a different response.", "I do not comprehend.", "Je neux comprend pas."], 1)
      print(els)
```

However, when it runs, it reads each word individually, I was wondering if there is something I could do to make it only run the most relevant combination of functions, rather than running an individual one for each, or if there is a way to make it read each word, and have combinations such as having both game and play in the input, and combining them to do an individual function, differing from one that only has one of them.